# Как сделать плавную замену блоков? css js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет! Не могу разобраться как сделать замену блоков с анимацией

Есть блок родитель - .form_block
Его дочерние эл-ты - .form и .form_after

.form_after изначально скрыт, нужно сделать плавное пропадание .form с уменьшением высоты у родителя .form_block до высоты .form_after и плавным появлением .form_after

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
<div class="form_block">
    <div class="form"></div>
    <div class="form_after"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В обработчике нажатия кнопки отправки добавляем родительскому блоку вспомогательный класс. Основываясь на наличии этого класса, изменяются необходимые свойства в стилях.

```js
document.querySelector(".form button").addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector(".form_block").classList.toggle("sending", true);
});
```

```css
.form_block {
  font: bold 14px/1em sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  height: 167px; width: 438px;
  border: 1px solid #d6323b;
  border-radius: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #0008;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.form_block.sending {
  height: 99px;
  transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}

.form_block > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  gap: 0.8em;
  height: 165px;
}
.sending .form {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity .6s ease-out;
}

.form p {
  font: bold 1.4em/1em sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
}

.form input {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #d6323b;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.form button {
  font: bold 1.2em/1em sans-serif;
  height: 44px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #d6323b;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form:invalid button {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: saturate(10%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form_after {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  gap: 17px;
  height: 99px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.sending .form_after {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  transition: opacity .6s ease-out .2s;
}

.form_after .icon {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -30px;
  height: 40px; width: 40px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  background-color: #e8979b;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 1px #6a6a6a;
}
.form_after .icon::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px; left: 21px;
  height: 10px; width: 17px;
  box-shadow: inset 4px -4px 0 #fff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1px #6a6a6a) drop-shadow(0 0 1px #6a6a6a) drop-shadow(0 0 .5px #6a6a6a) drop-shadow(0 0 .5px #6a6a6a);
}

.form_after p {
  font: bold 1.1em/1em sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -0.6px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #efefef;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="form_block">
  <form class="form">
    <p>Submit your application</p>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Your mail" required>
    <button>Send</button>
  </form>
  <div class="form_after">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <p>Thank you, I will contact you soon</p>
  </div>
</div>
```